# Please swap synonym suggestions around.

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

EDIT: Thanks to the downvoters! I have put the correct synonyms in now, <s>should you want to upvote them.</s> Complete! They are now in place.

---

I mistakenly [suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=left-4-dead&sort=info&pagesize=15) `[l4d2]` as a `[left-4-dead]` synonym and [suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=left-4-dead-2&sort=info&pagesize=15) `[l4d]` as a `[left-4-dead-2]` synonym.

Now I can't delete the suggestions or recreate them for the right tag as they're already suggested.

Could you please downvote this suggestions to hell or delete them so that we can put the right suggestions in?

Comment: You could also post a feature-request on meta.so to allow deletion of synonyms.

Comment: I don't see those suggestions at all.

Comment: @C.Ross That's because 3 people voted them down.

Comment: Downvoted and upvoting again, as requested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a reply to tell Community this question doesn't need any further bumping, as it has been resolved.

Comment: That wacky *community* has done it again. :) Isn't a checkmark required to stop it?

Comment: @Cyclops Or an upvote.

Comment: @StrixVaria, does an upvote stop *community* from bumping old posts? Is that new to SE 2.0? Because at least on UnityAnswers (an old SE 1.0 site), it doesn't.

Comment: @Cyclops It's been around on the Trilogy since before Area 51.

Comment: @Grace Note - *it* being the feature, that upvoting stops community-bumping? Cool, good to know. (Wish UA had it :(

Comment: @Cyclops Yes, the bumping. I can only really say that it's been around since before April 15th last year, as that's when I joined Meta.